# data load job failing with "Unexpected" error

Tags: google-bigquery

Errors: Unexpected. Please try again.

Job ID: aaaaaaaaa.com:bbbbbbbbb:job_F1GjqdmJj3JZWDToxh_xav9hwsg

Start Time: 11:10am, 14 Apr 2014

End Time: 1:10pm, 14 Apr 2014

Destination Table: aaaaaaaaaaa.com:bbbbbbbbb:monte.ledger2

No idea why this is failing - some succeed, some do not...

Answer (score 0):

Your import job is taking too long to process, so it is getting killed. We're reporting this as an internal error, which should be fixed to report a more user-friendly error instead.

We will also look into bumping the timeout (currently 2 hours per worker).

Workarounds for the issue include splitting your data into smaller files, or using uncompressed input files. The latter may sound surprising, but uncompressed files can be split into chunks and processed in parallel, but gzipped files cannot.

Comment: Thanks, I did see processing 10 files at a time instead of 100 improve the situation - but I did still see timeouts.

Are the individual files processed in parallel or sequentially?  I've been uploading 4GB .json.gz thusfar.

Comment: The files are processed in parallel. The issue is not the number of files but the size. Compressed JSON can expand by a large factor, and a single worker is having trouble processing a 4GB file in 2 hours.

Comment: Okay, thanks - I shall start to split my files into smaller pieces.

Comment: And another question - when the job fails in this way, are some rows loaded or no rows loaded?

Comment: Either all rows are loaded or none are... the whole job succeeds or none of it does.